# Check if verisign root certificate installed on phone

Tags: java-me, midp, j2mepolish, midp-2.0

Is there a method to check what root certificates are installed on a phone using midp ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anyway to get a list of root certificates on the phone from within a MIDlet. However most phones do allow you to navigate to a menu listing the root certificates. I think on most Nokia Series 40 phones it's located at Menu->Settings->Security->Authority Certificates.

I have experienced this problem myself when a Thawte root certificate was not on the phone. The only way you'll know is when you try to install your signed jar file and the phone states that you're installing an unsigned jar. The company I work for ended up forking out £300 for Verisign certificate!

I have read about people flashing root certificates on to phones, which might be an option. I would advise against this, there is no room for error!  I'm not responsible for any damage to your phone, and you do it at your own risk. You can see for how it was done on a Samsung Tocco - http://www.m2uu.com/komputery:samsungavilatocco.